# Асинхронная отправка GET запроса, вывод ответа в консоль

Tags: c#, api

Асинхронно отправляю некоторое количество запросов.

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var tasks = pairs.Select(pair => client.GetAsync(BinanceApi._depth_string_request(pair)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Как вывести в консоль ответы на все эти запросы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `GetAsync` возвращает типизированные объекты ([Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_String_)), т.е. передавая эти таски в `WhenAll`, он автоматически распакует результаты выполнения, в вашем случае HttpResponseMessage, а уже из него вы можете получать все что вам нужно, контент, статус код и т.д., например:

```
var pairs = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
using var client = new HttpClient();
var tasks = pairs.Select(pair => client.GetAsync($"https://postman-echo.com/get?foo={pair}"));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Если вам не нужен `HttpResponseMessage`, а просто результат, то можно попробовать `GetStringAsync` метод, который сразу возвращает строку ([MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetStringAsync_System_String_)).

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.